# How to map a String[] in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, arrays

How would you map the following class in hibernate:

```
private class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String[] chapterTitles;

    //Constructor, Getters and Setters
}
```

I have mapped Collections and primitive arrays in Hibernate, but how do I do it with a **String[]**? My hibernate tools stops with a 'NullPointerException' thereby I am unable to generate the mappings. And I have googled but couldn't find any.

Comment: This is a Webservice for a JME client which uses Simple XML to serialize objects into XML. The XML parser on the device written by another developer uses a generic parser to parse the contents. Changing the member as a Collection would generate a different XML element type which would break the JME app's parser.

Comment: would it? Normally an array and a list should be interchangeable when it comes to xml/json serialization

Comment: It's the name of the 'tag' that would change. I have to make changes to the other 'Model' classes to make them compatible which I don't prefer to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no clue how to do it with Annotations and personally, I don't think it's good idea and you should use `List<String>` however you can do it using xml mapping.

You should use `<array>`

```
<array name="chapterTytles" table="Titles">
    <key column="title_ID" />
    <index column="tytle_index" />
    <element column="tytle_name" type="string" />
</array>
```

Comment: Hi @danny, I have tried this already and I am getting the following exception: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: String, at table: Titles, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(title_ID)]

Comment: Please try string with the lower case, but the best use List<String> :)

Comment: When I use 'string' I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveType. Ok, I think I should use List<String> instead. Do you have any pointers for the List<String> as well?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by [creating a custom value type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom), although I would personally prefer to change your design and use a List instead.

Comment: Hi @Sean, how do I do it if I am using a List<String> instead?

Comment: @RagunathJawahar i though you had already mapped collections? Your question text says so.

Comment: Yes, I did that for List<MyObjects>, but haven't tried that for String yet. No issues, I have already found a work around. Thank you anyways.